# Methods to solve this equation on finite fields?

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear-equations

Is there any analytical (exact, closed-form solution) or numerical method to solve an equation such as

$p(x) = r^x$

where $p(x)$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are drawn from a finite field, and $r$ is a primitive root of the field modulus ?

Or, is this problem known to be equivalent to solving the discrete logarithm problem ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the finite field $\mathbb{F}$ has a number of elements that is small enough, you can obtain the Lagrange interpolation polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $f(x_i) = r^{x_i}$ for all elements $x_i \in \mathbb{F}$. This polynomial is *identical* to $r^{x}$ precisely because we are working on a finite field.  Then, the problem is reduced to finding the roots of the polynomial $g = p - f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$.  A brute-force approach consisting of trying every possible element in the field would work.  Another possibility would be to factor $g$ using [Berlekamp's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) and read the roots off the factors.

You can find further details on these types of algorithms (such as computational complexity, etc) in the computer algebra literature (see, for instance, [this](https://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/science/mca/) and [this](http://books.google.com/books/about/Polynomial_Algorithms_in_Computer_Algebr.html?id=rqhhlV046kMC)).

Comment: Thank you. But then, how much difficult is finding the roots of *p(x) - f(x)* ? Since we are not working in the continuous but in a finite field, what methods can be used and what is their complexity ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your questions.

Comment: Juan, thank you very much for the references. Exhaustive search, Berlekamp and Cantor–Zassenhaus algorithms require exponential time, exactly what I was hoping for since I want to apply this in the construction of a cryptographic protocol.